# Series object transform in nan when try to link to a another column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have problems to do a similar method from excel using vlookup in pandas.

#### Code:

```
def valorPrecoMaterial(result):
#grupping all materials, if the values repeat, chose the most expensive
valores_agrupados = Valores.groupby('Material').agg({'PrecoLiq':'max'}).reset_index()
#link the material 
result_preco = result.merge(valores_agrupados, on=['Material'], how='left')
return result_preco['PrecoLiq']

#adding coluns with the price of each material
Resultado['PRECO'] = valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado)
```

The exportation from my function "valorPrecoMaterial" works fine:

```
valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado).sum()
```

> out[32]: 5442781.95

But, when I try to include it in my result matrix, all values transform in `NaN`:

```
Resultado['PRECO'] = valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado) 
Resultado['PRECO'].sum()
```

> out[32]: 0

```
Resultado['PRECO']
```

> out[32]: 2514   NaN
>
> 2526   NaN
>
> 2515   NaN
>
> ...

I know that `valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado)` is a series value, but how can I link it in a column from another matrix without transforming all in `NaN` values?

Comment: If the index of `valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado)` doesn't match with `Resultado`, but you have an array with the same number of elements as `Resultado` has rows, you might just do `Resultado['PRECO'] = valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado).values`. This selects the array directly so there is no matching by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very likely that the index of the Series that you return does not match the index of the DataFrame. When you attempt to assign the values using a Series, pandas will attempt to align the indexes. Where they do not it will insert NaN values instead.

If you *know* the shape fits you can assign the values directly using:

`Resultado['PRECO'] = valorPrecoMaterial(Resultado).values`